# How mature is massive MIMO energy harvesting (in the 3GPP standards)?

Tags: mobile-data, standards, power-sources

About a year ago I attended a presentation where it was explained that a successful and thorough proof-of-concept for LTE massive MIMO had been conducted and was hopefully going to make it to into 5G<sup>1</sup>.

What stuck me more than anything was a possibility that massive MIMO might be [used to power small, low-power devices](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7569750/) directly.

Does anyone know how serious that suggestion is?  Is energy harvesting via massive MIMO also planned for a 3GPP standard? Any other information regarding the maturity of massive MIMO in the 3GPP standards would also be welcome.

<sup>1</sup><sub>From another source I've heard it suggested that massive MIMO will make it to an updated 4G standard.</sub>

Comment: Some material I've yet to read through regarding massive MIMO, 5G and energy harvesting: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.08689.pdf